# Is there any library to build generators for keras.Model.fit_generator?

Tags: machine-learning, tf.keras

`keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator` is used create Generators for Image input.

Is there any similar kind of library available for normal numpy array input?

Answer (score 0):

No I have not come across any such libraries but we can write a generator that does this for numpy array.

```
def gen(batch):
     j = 0 
     while True:
        x = np.array(x_shape)
        y = np.array(y_shape)
        for i in range(batch_size):
              x = read(batch[j])
              y = read(batch[j])
        j += 1
        yeild x,y
```

We can use this as a template, we are using generators because our data doesn't fit in RAM. we can also use an iterator instead of j when using multi-processing.